# Weird "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements" error... seems caused by iOS 8 sharing?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Due to iOS 8 sharing, I've had to create a bundle ID and provisioning profile for sharing. This new bundle ID is linked to my existing bundle ID through an app group, and my entitlements file specifies the app group. Now, however, my wildcard provisioning profile doesn't work. When I try to build, Xcode says "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements". Only when I use the provisioning profile with a specific bundle ID does it work. It's becoming a huge issue for my company.

Any ideas? We want to use a wildcard because we add devices a lot, and a wildcard doesn't require a refresh of our provisioning profiles for all the devs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you need to use special entitlements (iCloud, push notifications, etc.) you can no longer use wildcard IDs.  You will need to create a unique ID on Apple's dev site for each of your app that needs these capabilities, if each of the apps need to be installed at the same time on one device.

If your different apps will never need to be installed by the same person, you could get by having multiple apps use the same bundle ID, but I wouldn't recommend it.  If someone has App A on the device, and at some point in the future needs to install app B, it will replace it, and could cause problems if the app uses things like Core Data.